# Is there any information about what Alan Moore had in mind for expanding the Watchmen franchise?

Tags: dc, watchmen, alan-moore

Alan Moore stated [back in 1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchmen) that if the original Watchmen mini-series was well-received, he and Gibbons would possibly create a 12-issue prequel series called Minutemen featuring the 1940s superhero group from the story.

However, due to contract disputes, Moore ended his association with DC Comics in 1989.

In 2010, Moore said in an interview that

> "[DC Comics] offered me the rights to Watchmen back, if I would agree to some dopey prequels and sequels," [...]
>
> "So I just told them that if they said that 10 years ago, when I asked them for that, then yeah it might have worked," he said. "But these days I don't want Watchmen back. Certainly, I don't want it back under those kinds of terms."
>
> <sub>["Alan Moore: 'I don't want *Watchmen* back'"](https://www.wired.com/underwire/2010/07/alan-moore-watchmen), interview with *Wired*, October 2010</sub>

This implies that roughly 10 years after Moore ended his association with DC, there was some dialog about him wanting to do more Watchmen content.

Is there any more information about this dialog?  Was he referring to the original idea of adding the Minutemen prequel series, or were there perhaps other ideas involved?  Was Dave Gibbons part of this discussion?

Comment: Funny you asked this today. Did you see the same [ScreenRant article](http://screenrant.com/watchmen-prequel-dc-comics-kofi-149230/) I did?

Comment: Actually, no, I saw it announced on [Wired.com](http://www.wired.com/underwire/2012/02/exclusive-before-watchmen/) after someone mentioned it in chat.  I suspect its all over the Net today :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**From Page 3 of 8 of an Interview with Alan Moore, hosted by Seraphemera Books: The first reference to the Minutemen storylines that Moore wanted to do before his falling out with DC Comics:**

> KA: I'm not in complete agreement with you about the quality of comics
>   that have come out since Watchmen.  There have been some great books
>   since then--none of them as good as Watchmen, admittedly, but still
>   well-worth reading.  But, one thing that amazes me about all this is
>   that they're not just putting out a 12-issue prequel miniseries or one
>   graphic novel.  I've heard you and Dave Gibbons had even discussed
>   doing a Minutemen prequel decades ago.  But Before Watchmen crosses
>   through 35 comics.  It will cost nearly $140 for someone to buy all of
>   them.  That sounds like they loaded every story idea they had into a
>   cannon and lit the fuse.  Even if I was interested in reading this, it
>   would still seem like overkill.
>
> AM:  It would seem to me that in bringing out 35 books--even if these,
>   for some reason, sell remarkably well; even if there are some people
>   out there who are so undiscriminating that they are going to have to
>   collect every one of these books--even if that happens, that is not
>   going to generate enough money to reverse the comics industry's
>   rapidly declining fortunes.  That's not the reason why they're
>   bringing these things out.  I don't think that DC are interested in
>   comics anymore.  They're interested in growing franchises, like a
>   pumpkin patch.  Hollywood--now that's where you make the real money,
>   or in computer games, or in any of these franchise spin-offs.  I might
>   be wrong, I don't really know very much about how these corporations
>   work.  But, I think what they're hoping to do with this raft of titles
>   is spin off some new miniseries, television movies, or computer
>   games--merchandising.  That's the only thing that makes it valuable to
>   them.  They don't appear to have noticed that Watchmen is an ensemble
>   piece.  Actually, none of those characters really work on their own. 
>   They work in the context of the story.

---

> **An Interview with Alan Moore**
>
> Often The Truth gets lost in The Sound Bite. An extensive and
>   exclusive interview about Watchmen and Beyond Watchmen.   Mr. Moore
>   gave a quote here, a comment there.  Spoke a little about what it
>   meant that DC was going to revisit these characters he created.  But
>   his full statement has never been revealed--only quoted.
>
> Seraphemera Books offered Moore the chance to speak his mind however
>   he should see fit.  As we’re as indie as it gets, we’re beholden to no
>   concerns outside of providing the loudspeaker for the voice of
>   somebody who, while his stories are widely read and revered, doesn’t
>   often get the opportunity to write the story about himself.
>
> At Moore's invitation, Seraphemera Books comic writer Kurt Amacker
>   conducted a ninety minute interview with the legendary creator. 
>   Amacker has conducted a series of interviews with Moore since 2006. 
>   The end result is less a collection of terse bullet points than a
>   revealing and uncensored conversation between two creators--one, the
>   best the medium has ever seen; the other, an independent at the very
>   start of his career in comics.
>
> So here it is - the transcript of a ninety minute interview, between
>   Mr. Moore (The Watchmen, V for Vendetta, Batman:  The Killing Joke,
>   and so much more), and seraphemera books writer Kurt Amacker (Tad
>   Caldwell, Dead Souls, Immortal:60).
>
> Revealing, personal, uncensored and unchecked.  This is Alan Moore as
>   you've rarely heard him.  Some stories are familiar.  Some stories are
>   new...and shocking...and sad.  Read on for an intimate look at the
>   architect of modern comics, and his long and personal struggle with
>   the very industry he helped to elevate.
>
> So, listen up.  Come along for a true story so gruesome you’d never
>   believe it, if somebody wrote it as fiction. Well, nobody except for
>   Alan Moore...
>
> [Click here to start reading on Page 1](http://www.seraphemera.org/seraphemera_books/AlanMoore_Page1.html)

This multi-page interview will answer any questions you may have had about what Alan Moore thought of his work and time with DC Comics, his opinions of the work being done with the pre-Watchmen storylines and how his time with DC has left him of the mind to NEVER work with DC again. Well worth every minute of the transcript.

Comment: I'd love to upvote this, but it will have to wait until I can go through the entire interview.  As it stands now, you aren't actually answering the question, but rather providing a link to a resource which hopefully can help answer the question. Feel free to add in any specific excerpts that address the question; if I come across any when I get a chance to go through it in depth, I'll edit them into your answer and upvote/accept.

Comment: I did find the specific quotation mentioning the Minutemen but it was difficult to extract it without the risk of losing the surrounding context. It seemed more appropriate to let other decide how to interpret Moore's words rather than butcher the paragraphs where it is discussed.